# Nuclio Streaming Contents Support? (Docker setup - Python)

Tags: python, docker, nuclio

Is there support for streaming back a response in Nuclio? The workflow I'm trying to achieve is to have the UI request a large file from a Nuclio function running inside a docker container and having it stream back the large file.

For example this is how Flask supports streaming contents:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/streaming/

I can't seem to find anywhere that mentions how to have Nuclio stream back large data/file.
I do see they mention some stuff about stream triggers, but I don't know if that'll help with streaming back the response:

https://nuclio.io/docs/latest/concepts/architecture/

https://nuclio.io/docs/latest/reference/triggers/

If there's no support, would my best bet be to stream the data to some 3rd party platform and have the UI download the data/file from there?